# how to debug in mixed mode in C# with Microsoft Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: c#

I tried to follow the following descriptions to be able to debug in Mixed Mode, but which is for C++, haven't found one for C# :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kbaht4dh(v=vs.120).aspx

However in Configuration Properties, I don't have the Debugging option.

Can C# be debugged in Mixed Mode?

Here is what I have in the properties of my project:

Project > Properties >

Common Properties > Startup Project / Project Dependencies / Code Analysis Settings / Debug Source Files

Configuration Properties > Configuration

Comment: Project > Properties > Debug > tick the "Enable native code debugging" option.  Spend a couple of hours looking around, this is supposed to be discoverable.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for the answer! I don't see it in my options however. In the description I added what I have

Comment: You need to stop looking at the Solution properties.   If you don't want to follow my advice then at least right-click the project and not the solution node.

Comment: @CherrysaHerrim: getting defensive because someone gives you a little Gibbs slap isn't going to do you any good.  Rather, take it for what it is, a wake up call to pay more attention.  Programming is a precise business.  You need to pay attention to the details.

Answer (score 0):

Project > Properties > Debug > tick the "Enable native code debugging" option.

From Hans Passant in the comments.